# PuppetMaster hits depracated API of PuppetDb not sure why

Tags: puppet

Following is the error that I get when I try to run the command `puppet agent -t` on Puppet Agent. It happens when PuppetServer tries to reach V3 of PuppetDb instead of V4, although the V3 is depracated, and should not be called ideally. Not sure how to fix this.

All the configs are in place as defined here : http://jurjenbokma.com/ApprenticesNotes/ar27s05.xhtml

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Failed to submit 'replace facts' command for puppetmaster.test.org to PuppetDB at puppetmaster.test.org:8081: [404 ] <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/><title>Error 404 </title></head><body><h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2><p>Problem accessing /v3/commands. Reason:<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i></body></html>
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Answer (score 1):

I was following a tutorial for an older version, whereas, for latest version (Puppet v4.x) we need to have different modules.
There is an interface between PuppetMaster and PuppetDb which is responsible for making API calls to PuppetDb, in the link being followed it asks to install

`sudo puppet resource package`**puppetdb-terminus**`ensure=latest` which uses `/v3` api of PuppetDb, whereas, for the latest version we need to install

`sudo puppet resource package`**puppetdb-termini**`ensure=latest`
which uses `/v4` api of PuppetDb...

And the problem is solved!

Comment: Thanks for updating with the answer.